# AzureDevOps Yaml Task Environment Variable not working

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a node application in azure devops and I am struggling with the following issue. I need to set an environment variable that is picked up with the code, but it looks like I am no hitting the point

**Yaml:**

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
- name: VERBOSE
  displayName: 'Verbose'
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: install
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/schemas'
    verbose: false
    customRegistry: useNpmrc
  displayName: 'Install npm'

- task: CmdLine@2
  env:
    VERBOSE: ${{ parameters.VERBOSE }}
  inputs:
    script: 'node app.js' 
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/schemas'
  displayName: 'Run app.js'
```

at the first line of app.js I set a ***console.log(process.env["VERBOSE"])***, but nothing is displayed.
Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check whether it fails on assignment or evaluation.

**If you change the default parameter value, is it reflected?**

If not, fix that first. If yes, then start figuring out how to assign the parameter correctly. Right now it's impossible to tell which of these needs fixing.

Comment: If I change the parameter default value and/or set it manually, it is still not showing on node execution. I just create a task that only prints the parameter and it's assignment is correct

Answer (score 0):

This is the YAML on my side:

```
trigger:
- none


parameters:
- name: VERBOSE
  displayName: 'Verbose'
  type: boolean
  default: false

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'ls'
- task: CmdLine@2
  env:
    VERBOSE: ${{ parameters.VERBOSE }}
  inputs:
    script: 'node app.js' 
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/schemas'
  displayName: 'Run app.js'
```

My repo structure:

[image]

I can get the value successfully:

[image]

Try to use the above simply demo, could the value appear on your side?

Comment: I use this example and the value doen't appear. It looks like an issue with the boolean parameter, as I replace it with a string one and I can see the value